# Eleventy : collection filtered by a custom tag (Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length'))

Tags: javascript, node.js, eleventy

I'm new to eleventy and js in general, sorry, I feel that my question is a quite simple one but I'm not finding anything in the documentation, and the error is too general for me.

I have notes in a collection, with a frontmatter like this :

```
---
[…]
notetype: feed //or unfeed
[…]
---
```

I'm trying to use the pagination function in eleventy to display only the notes who are notetype = "feed".

I tried to create a collection in eleventy.js :

```
  eleventyConfig.addCollection("feed", function(collectionApi) {
    return collectionApi.getAll().forEach(item => {
      if (item.data.notetype == "feed")
      return item;
    });
  });
```

I think the problem is in my syntax of this bit of code, but as I was saying, I don't know node or this type of js, and I'm a bit lost.

The error the consol is throwing at me :

```
[11ty] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') (via TypeError)
[11ty] 
[11ty] Original error stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

The repo is [here](https://codeberg.org/yazae101/yazae.garden/src/branch/pagination) if necessary even if I don't think the error is elswhere, when I'm commenting the collection everything build without errors.

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `forEach` which doesn't return anything. And the next step processing the result from your function is expecting some collection (probably an array). Use `Array.filter` instead

```
eleventyConfig.addCollection("feed", function(collectionApi) {
    return collectionApi.getAll().filter(item => {
      return (item.data.notetype == "feed")!
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, it was what I was searching for !